# upload file only when format is jpg/png

Tags: php

I have written this script to let users upload a profile picture:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $path = $_FILES["uploaded_image"]["name"];
  $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //extracts file extension

  $tempimgloc = $_FILES["uploaded_image"]["tmp_name"];

  $imagepic = ''.$_SESSION['userid'].'-'.$_SESSION['username'].'.'.$ext.'';
  $img_url = 'img/uploaded/'.$imagepic.'';

if(move_uploaded_file($tempimgloc, "img/uploaded/".$imagepic)){
 mysql_query('UPDATE table SET img = "'.$img_url.'" WHERE userid = '.$_SESSION['userid'].'');
  echo '<script>window.location = "success.php";</script>';
} else {
  echo 'error';
 }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to let them only upload files with the extension `png` or `jpg`.

I tried to add this to the upper if-statement but it did not work out:

```
if($ext == 'jpg' or $ext == 'png'){
...
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `var_dump($ext)`? That should make you figure out why it isn't working

Comment: Do not use mysql_query. Read the big red box on http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: `It doesn't work` -> does that mean that ALL file types are uploaded or NO files at all are uploaded? And you do realize that if you add this to your first `if` statement (`if(isset(...))`) that the `$ext` variable is still empty?

Comment: may I add to this that checking the extension is quite useless in terms of security? I can write a malicious script, change the file extension to `.jpg` and it'll be allowed to be uploaded anyway, and executed using some other loophole. A better way of checking is using `getimagesize()` and the return element with index 2 (checkout [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and [list of image-related constants](http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php)